# Please advise me on Java mobile app

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, mobile, symbian

I am new to Java and I want to create a Java app for mobiles. When I approached software companies they asked for "Android / Blackberry / Symbian" etc...

Being a newb, I am really surprised by these questions. Can you please tell me whether there are any other mobile platforms in Java?

Are Blackberry apps and Java mobile apps different? And what is the target phone for j2ME applications?

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development) it can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 6):

Java ME is [waning](http://www.google.com/trends?q=javame,%20android&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=1).

iPhone is Objective-C; there's no Java on iPhone.

Android is its own platform, different from Java ME.

BlackBerry used to be based on Java ME, but they're moving in an HTML/CSS/JavaScript direction, away from Java ME.

Answer (score 2):

j2me is a technology that was used a couple of years ago for creating those apps on the cheap phones (think pre-smartphones). blackberry and symbian have a bit of an extended java libraries but it is still similar to j2me (painful to create apps that don't look good plus in later global events symbian os is becoming more and more unpopular which means less and less developers are needed).

But basically the major part of the mobile apps are written in java, one way of another. there is also IOS which uses xCode. maybe even some embedded development platforms that are using c++ or something but i can't really say for those.

EDIT:

Oh and yes there is windows mobile now that is becoming quite popular. getting into windows 7 mobile development is actually a good idea in my opinion. Although currently its pretty poor in terms of available resources community etc.. it can possibly grow in the next year or two. Plus the app competitions is quite small, there isn't a market so its easier to push through a successful app (which isn't the case with iphone and also the android market becomes filled really fast).

Answer (score 1):

J2ME only supports on Symbian and Blackberry platform. [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) is J2ME framework. You can develop symbian, blackberry and android application by using this framework. If you are using LWUIT framework means no need to write the coding for different platform. You can use same coding for [all platform](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html)(Symbian, Balckberry and Android). But you have change some small changes for each platform.

Basically iPhone supports objective-C. But you can develop the iPhone application by using C# with [MonoTouch framework.](http://monotouch.net/) If you know java means C# with MonoTouch framework better for iPhone development. But it will be cost.